# Bxslider slider shown only one slide

Tags: slider, bxslider

Bxslider slider shown only one slide, space between slider is very big or what is problem i can't figure out

it shows 1 slide after scorollin 2nd slide e.t.c.

but i want to 5 slidere scrolling alway like carousel

```html
.bx-wrapper {
 position: relative;
 margin: 0 auto 20px;
 padding: 0;
 *zoom: 1;
 width: 780px;
   height: 100px;
}

.bx-wrapper img {
 max-width: 20%;
 display: block;
}

/** THEME
===================================*/

.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport {
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff;
 box-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff;
 border:  5px solid #fff;
 left: -5px;
 background: #fff;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this sample, i need auto too, in this example, http://bxslider.com/examples/carousel-dynamic-number-slides

```js
 SCRIPT

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.bxslider').bxSlider();
});
</script>
```

```html
HTML 

  <ul class="bxslider">
  <li><img src="images/logo1" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/logo2" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/logo3" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/logo4" /></li>
  </ul>
```

```js
   <!-- jQuery library (served from Google) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- bxSlider Javascript file -->
<script src="/js/bxslider/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<!-- bxSlider CSS file -->
<link href="/js/bxslider/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: It will be better if I contact you, if u have a time?

Answer (score 0):

Strange thing,

I added your code,  now no scrolling and everything is vertical not horizontal.

I'm edited before something, but not js, I think something going wrong, but can't figure out

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
      var bx = $('.bx').bxSlider({
        auto: true,
        autoControls: true,
        minSlides: 5,
        maxSlides: 5,
        moveSlides: 5,
        slideWidth: 120

      })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Ok, Now  it's work, sorry, i'm new here , is it possible to contact you?

Comment: Ok ,sorry for disturbing, and gracias!

Comment: It's working as i said , but another one question, 1)  slider not in the center of page, whole slider  I mean BOX. 2) not carousel, just show all images and after stoped, what can it be?

Comment: As i see it's not carousel, that's why it's not in center , 'cause when it stoped one of the slide hidden

Comment: I mean there are scrolling image by image (shows 5), but after that they stoped, i want to scroll them always without stoping, something like autoreload after scroll all images